# Build text callout with PDF Clown

Tags: java, adobe, pdfclown

the adobe acrobat reader have markup tool called "text callout".

It's possible to build with PDF Clown a object of this type?

Comment: Please link to a sample PDF with such a text callout. And what have you tried?

Comment: You can get sample file here: http://www.file-upload.net/download-11825556/testfilewithtextcallout.pdf.html

I want create a text callout with PDF Clown library. It's possible?

Comment: It is not clear where i can download there. I only see ads.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! I edited your question as far as I could guess your problem. However, add code and description so that more people with knowledge of the subject will see it. Please edit in the specific error-message you're encountering in case that's necessary to identify the specific problem. Good Luck!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The sample provided by the OP looks pretty much like the PDF Clown `StaticNote` with a `StaticNote.CalloutLine`.

The relevant code from the `AnnotationSample` PDF Clown cli example are:

```
// Callout.
composer.showText("Callout note annotation:", new Point(35, 85));
new StaticNote(
  page,
  new Rectangle(250, 90, 150, 70),
  "Text of the Callout note annotation"
  ).withLine(
     new StaticNote.CalloutLine(
       page,
       new Point(250,125),
       new Point(150,125),
       new Point(100,100)
       )
     )
   .withLineEndStyle(LineEndStyleEnum.OpenArrow)
   .withBorder(new Border(1))
   .withColor(DeviceRGBColor.get(Color.YELLOW));
```

*(From [AnnotationSample.java](https://sourceforge.net/p/clown/code/HEAD/tree/trunk/java/pdfclown.samples.cli/src/org/pdfclown/samples/cli/AnnotationSample.java))*

The output:

[image: screenshot of <code>AnnotationSample</code> result]

Comment: Thank you for your detailed reply, I will try with StaticNote.

Comment: @godani And, did you succeed?

Comment: Sry, but it doesn't work. I can't import library "org.pdfclown.documents.interaction.annotations.StaticNote". I get error message: "The import org.pdfclown.documents.interaction.annotations.LineEndStyleEnum cannot be resolved".  How do the import works right?

Comment: In that case you have a much more basic problem. Either you don't have pdf clown on your build path at all or only a very old version of it.

Comment: I had downloaded and imported PDF Clown 0.1.2.0 from "https://pdfclown.org/downloads/". Is this not the current Version?

Comment: The original 0.1.2.0 indeed is too old, it is dated 10.02.2013. The next release after 0.1.2 should have been 0.2.0, but as that release got more and more delayed, the PDF Clown author provided some changes and additions in the [0.1.2-Fix branch](https://svn.code.sf.net/p/clown/code/branches/0.1.2-Fix) and [trunk](https://svn.code.sf.net/p/clown/code/trunk) in 2015. Either version contains `StaticNote`. Either checkout one of those branches from the svn repository or for trunk use the ZIP under "PDF Clown HEAD", "Latest Development Snapshot" on the downloads page.

Comment: Now it works well, thanky you very much! It is possible to get coordinates where text end on left and right side on page?

Comment: @godani Do you mean the text in the annotation? Or do you mean content text on a page? In the former case I don't know. In the latter case please make it a separate Question here as it is a topic on its own right.

Comment: Concerning this question: As you say it now works well, you probably should accept the answer (click on the tick at its upper left).

Comment: I mean the Content text on a page. I have post this question under this link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39102237/get-coordinates-of-content-area-at-pdf

Comment: Yes, i will do it. Thanks for your support!

Comment: Ah, I just see your new question has been put on hold. I think it is because it is expected on stackoverflow that you try to find out yourself and, if you get stuck on the way, present your pivotal code and explain the issue ("This is where I got stuck, I expected XXX to happen but I observe YYY.").

Comment: @godani Unfortunately you had not also tagged that other question with [tag:pdf]; it would have made re-opening it easier.